# Preview Google Play app listing

Tags: android, google-play

I am preparing my first publication in Google Play and have found that there are a limited number of formatting tags accepted in the full description.

However, I have just found that Google does not provide any form of previewing of this description - having spoken to Google.

Does anyone know of a workaround for doing this ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: So, @CommonsWare, I understand that this should not be asked here. So where then ? Google has already answered me with a shrug = not much help there !

Comment: Try [a different Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com/).